# Hourly data for Ethereum?

Tags: ether, price

Is there any reliable source for hourly data for Ethereum dating back to 2017? The poloniex API only provides me with daily data - https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=USDT_ETH&start=1480360203&end=9999999999&period=14400

Comment: I have not specific answer for this. However, you could just get blocks from hour X to Y. You can determinate block numbers by calculating how many blocks have been creating since a specific period (block time is around 15 seconds.)